# DB-fiddle query not giving the same result as own mysql database

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm building a node.js app that sends a reminder when I set them.
These reminders get stored in a mysql database and I'm checking every minute if there are any reminders due.
So currently I have a bit of code that runs every minute and runs a query to see if the current time lines up with the remind-time. That should return a table with reminders that are due right now so I can iterate through them and remind people.
This sounds simple enough but I'm having loads of trouble with it.
I created a mock database on DB-fiddle because that works a lot nicer with testing queries and as expected, I easily created a query that returns any reminders that are due.
When I posted this query into my code however it just started returning 0 results and I can't figure out why.

This is the SQL I used to create and fill the table on DB-fiddle. (the list of DATETIMES is the date and time it is at the time of testing to actually see results returned)
I then created the following query:

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
`id` int auto_increment primary key,
  `moment` datetime
);



INSERT INTO `test` (`moment`) VALUES
('2022-05-17 15:00:00'),
('2022-05-17 15:01:00'),
('2022-05-17 15:01:00'),
('2022-05-17 14:33:00'),
('2022-05-17 14:32:00'),
('2022-05-17 14:31:00'),
('2022-05-17 14:30:00'),
('2022-05-17 14:29:00'),
('2022-05-17 14:37:00'),
('2022-05-17 14:21:00');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME((ROUND(TIME_TO_SEC(NOW())/60)) * 60), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') as current FROM test WHERE DATE_FORMAT(moment, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') = DATE_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME((ROUND(TIME_TO_SEC(NOW())/60)) * 60), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s');
```

| id | moment | current |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2022-05-17 15:01:00 | 2022-05-17 15:01:00 |
| 3 | 2022-05-17 15:01:00 | 2022-05-17 15:01:00 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/prdQwXDe9NmxyjWpGZR6Ep/1)

This worked in DB-fiddle but not in my own database so I decided to paste these exact codes into my database to exactly recreate it. It still didn't work however and I can't figure it out.

Below is the relevant javascript code.

```
//Block of code that runs every minute
connection.query(`SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME((ROUND(TIME_TO_SEC(NOW())/60)) * 60), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') as current FROM Reminders WHERE DATE_FORMAT(moment, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') = DATE_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME((ROUND(TIME_TO_SEC(NOW())/60)) * 60), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')`, function (error, results, fields) {
console.log(results)
if (error) throw error;
});
```

This logs:

```
[]
```

Running SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%"; in the mysql client returns that I have version 8.0.29 which is what I have selected in db-fiddle too.

I'm really confused and hope anybody can clear this up for me.

Comment: ```SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:00') as current FROM Reminders WHERE DATE_FORMAT(moment, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:00') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:00');```. If second part in `moment` is always zero then `WHERE moment = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:00')`

Comment: *This worked in DB-fiddle but not in my own database* Check timezone. For debugging - remove WHERE but add both expressions from it to the output list.

Comment: @Akina Thanks that solved it. For some reason Mysql was reading everything from a different timezone than in another place in my app where I also used Date and time, that's why it never came up in my mind. Also that's a nice trick for debugging, def using that in the future.

Comment: *For some reason Mysql was reading everything from a different timezone* Use DATETIME column datatype, not TIMESTAMP.